# Performing a simple find operation in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

Using CakePHP, I need to retrieve a basic list of records.  No joins or special CakePHP result formatting, just a basic array of records in the following data format:

```
[
    {first_name: 'Matthew', last_name: 'Stafford', gender: 'male'},
    {first_name: 'Jason', last_name: 'Hanson', gender: 'male'}
]
```

What's the simplest way to do this using Cake Models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With proper MVC separation, outputting a *JSON formatted result* like that would look something like this:

Controller:

```
$people = $this->Person->find('all', array('conditions' => ...));
$this->set(compact('people'));
```

View:

```
echo json_encode(array_map(function ($p) { return $p['Person']; }, $people));
```

Comment: In your view, you can also use the JavaScript helper to create json result by doing "echo $this->Js->object($results);"

Comment: Sorry, no JSON involved in this question.  That's only the format of the data that I want the model method to return.

Comment: @Brad Then I'm not quite sure why you want this. I think it'll just make things messier if you *do* retrieve results with associations as well and are using different formats in different places. The default Cake format is verbose, but flexible and a decent *standard*.

Comment: The rationale is that the application uses a standard AJAX library with a send method that automatically encodes whatever data you hand it.  The client side programmer was requesting data in the specified format.  Fair point though; we'll discuss leaving the response in cake format.

Comment: @Brad Then I think my answer is spot on. If it *is* for communicating with a client, you only need to format the response in the view. In the Controller/Model/View itself you can/should use the standard Cake format.

Comment: I like trying to keep my views a bit slimmer on doing processing to the data than that, but you're right, it is presentation logic and under strict MVC belongs in the view.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to add the following method to the AppModel:

```
function selectAll($options = array()) {
    $this->recursive = 0;
    $result = $this->find('all', $options);

    return Set::combine($result, "{n}.{$this->name}.{$this->primaryKey}", "{n}.{$this->name}");
}
```

Comment: Still open to less intrusive answers, if someone has one.